# Form not passing data, PHP

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm working a small management application and it requires us to to be able to upload images that are being trademarked, but in short I'm having problems retrieving the data to process it, after some debugging I've figure out that the form isn't passing any data to the `$_FILES` superglobal, and I can't figure out why.
This is the relevant form code:

```
<form 
   action="/contracts/entity/save_entity/trademark" 
   method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   id="manage-entity-form"
>
   <input 
      type="hidden" 
      id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" 
      name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" 
      value="102400000" 
   />
   <label for="file" class="">
     <span class="ui-button-text">Image</span>
   </label>
   <input 
      type="file" 
      id="file" 
      class="ui-state-active" 
      name="data[Upload][]" 
   />
</form>
```

Comment: I'll bet a beer the problem is this: `data[Upload][]` what happens if you name it just "upload"?

Comment: What's with the `data[Upload][]` input name?  That may be causing the problem.  Try just `data`.

Comment: the names are fine. thats how you send arrays.

Comment: is it not submitting anything? _POST also empty? or only _FILES?

Comment: @Tobias: I'm not sure... I've seen formats like `data[]`, but not like this.  How would that come out in `$_FILES`?  Sample `print_r`?

Comment: @Pekka: It's not the name. I just ran his code myself and `count($_FILES)` showed one file, as expected. I don't think this is a problem with his code.

Comment: In that case, the problem must be elsewhere.  @Will could file uploading be disabled in your `php.ini`?

Comment: @Will: Can you show us the code which processes this form as well. I don't think the form itself is the problem, because I tested it and was able to receive a file without issue.

Comment: @AgentConundrum re `count($_FILES)`, fair enough. @Will a `print_r($_FILES);`  is definitely empty?

Comment: I also tested this code and it works for me as expected. @Will run `phpinfo()` and check `file_uploads`, `max_file_uploads`, `upload_max_filesize`, and maybe `upload_tmp_dir` for anything off.

Comment: I realized that the problem was I was passing the form via AJAX, which by default isn't allowed, so with a quick jQuery plugin search I found a way to do it and everything works well now, thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 2):

The multipart/form-data encoding does not support multidimensional arrays - see this thread: [How to upload files (multipart/form-data) with multidimensional POSTFIELDS using PHP and CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453353/how-to-upload-files-multipart-form-data-with-multidimensional-postfields-using/3454266#3454266)

Comment: I just used OPs form to upload two images (I added a second `input type="file"`, obviously), and display them in the response page. It *can* be done.