# How to get PHP CURL to format an array of arguments according to PHP's own specification?

Tags: php, curl

PHP requires query keys with multiple values to have [] at the end. For example:

```
<input name="key[]" />
<input name="key[]" />
```

The reason this is frustrating is, when I use CURL in PHP, the PHP implementation of CURL won't convert the array back appropriately. Instead, it just passes `key=Array`.

**I don't want to build the query string from scratch, because I might be transferring files at the same time (which requires CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to be an array)**

```
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arguments);
```

Any ideas how to get this to work? I want CURL to format the query string the way PHP would expect to see it if there were multiple values for one key.

Comment: I think this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453353/how-to-upload-files-multipart-form-data-with-multidimensional-postfields-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arguments = array (
  'key[0]' => 'value1',
  'key[1]' => 'value2',
);
```

Comment: The key needs an index value, array('key[0]' => 'value1').